# .NET C# : external changes to database not being retrieved by DbContext

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have added and updated information to my local database manually and when I try to retrieve it with EF, it is returning the old data.

In my Server Explorer, when I see the information from the table that I updated in my database, it shows the updated data, it seems like the `DbContext` is not retrieving the updated information from the database.

I tried to do a migration and call `update-database` but it did nothing, it seems like the information is rather static and stored elsewhere instead of going to the database to get the updated info.

Sorry if I'm not giving too much detail, I am kinda new to this `DbContext` & Entity Framework scene, please feel free to ask for more information in the comments, but it is basically this.

Comment: are you checking the correct database ?! check your `connectionString`.

Comment: if you try to restart you application do you than see the changes?
if not, check if you are reading from the same database.

Comment: The EF DbContext uses a caching mechanism - so if you change data "behind" the DbContext's back, yes, the DbContext will keep providing the cached ("old" / "stale") data for those keys it had fetched the data for before you made the changes. For other data (that hasn't been loaded/cached before your changes), the new data should be retrieved and shown. You can get around this by tossing out the DbContext you're using, and re-creating a new instance - then you should get the new data.

Comment: Keep DbContext lifespans short. This means for MVC/Web applications PerRequest or shorter if using Dependency Injection, or `using ( var context = new AppDbContext()) {  }` rather than initializing a longer scoped (global or class-level) context.  Once an entity is loaded and tracked, The DbContext will return that entity from cache when requested. Changes made to the DB since it was loaded will *not* automatically refresh the cached copy. Fetching /w `AsNoTracking()` will prevent EF from caching. Using `context.Entry(entity).Reload()` will reload an entity from DB. (if tracked by context)